# Showing courses in two blocks by category in Moodle Dashboard

Tags: moodle, dashboard

We have Moodle site v.3.6.3+ and we are trying to customise the view of dashboard.

We have 10 courses with 2 main categories, and need to display each category courses in a separate block in the dashboard.

Students may be enrolled in 2 courses from the first category and enrolled in 3 courses from the second category. So we need to display the enrolled courses of first category in one block and the other enrolled courses of second category in the other block.

We searched for a plugin which may  provides this feature, but with no luck.

Comment: Can you please share picture of current visibility of 'my courses'.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "Recently accessed block" in your dashboard and look for the "myoverview" and "recentlyaccssedcourses" folders under block in your application directly. You might have to look forward about how the code is written in "myoverview" block and modify the "recentlyaccssedcourses" accordingly. Since, I am also working on the same this is as far as i reached.

Answer (score 0):

I try to duplicate the myoverview block as a new one. Making all the proper changes to create a new block. I also use grunt to recreate the amd modules.
But something was missing because wasn't loading the courses.

I fix this by using pure js, duplicating the node element of the block, and filtering it with js.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).